# Edit Windows Key on Mouse/Keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

So I just got the new Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse:
http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-ergonomic-mouse/L6V-00001

The built in software allows you to edit all the buttons, except the big blue windows button. So its technically a 5 button mouse, but the software only allows you to edit 4 of the buttons.

I was wondering, if there was some way... maybe though registry edits or something, where I can change the function of the windows button on this mouse.

Same question applies to keyboards.